# How to use jQuery to find content in handle bar template

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I want to parse the html within `<figure class="kg-card kg-bookmark-card"></figure>` in the `{{content}}` of [Ghost post class](https://ghost.org/docs/themes/contexts/post/).

```
<article class="{{post_class}}">
    <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
    <script src="{{asset "built/post.js"}}"></script>
    <script>
        getBookmark(`${$({{content}}).find("figure.kg-card kg-bookmark-card:first")}`);
    </script>
</article>
```

`getBookmark()` exists in `post.js` and I am logging it for now but in the future, I want to use the result from parsing the html within `<figure class="kg-card kg-bookmark-card"></figure>` to modify the href of the article.

The above function is not working and it's throwing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (at ...)". The line of the error is:

```
getBookmark(`${$({{content}}).find("figure.kg-card kg-bookmark-card:first")}`)
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what the template string would be for (ie., what using the backticks is intended to do). I would assume you need something like: `$(function () { getBookmark($('{{content}}').find("figure.kg-card.kg-bookmark-card:first")); });`

Comment: Additionally, the error you have shared makes me wonder what the value of `{{content}}` is.

Comment: @76484 The value of `{{content}}` is plane HTML. Like `<h1> Lorem</h1> <p> Lorem Ipsum </p> ...`

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do by passing that to the jQuery function `$()`. You should probably be passing a selector to this function, like `$('document')`.

Comment: @76484 How might that work? `{{content}}` is not rendered on the page. I need to find the first `figure` node that has these classes `figure.kg-card kg-bookmark-card`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not completely. Is the `figure` element within the `content` value?

Comment: @76484 Yes, `figure` is in the `{{content}}` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues with the code you have posted.

If `content` is a string of HTML, then you will need to use the triple-mustache tags in order to render it without escaping:`{{{content}}}`.

Wrapping the entire jQuery expression as a template string will mean JavaScript will see it as a string instead of code to execute. Instead, you want to wrap the backticks around `{{{content}}}` only.

The selector `"figure.kg-card kg-bookmark-card:first"` doesn't make sense because `kg-bookmark-card` is not being used as a class. I think this should be: `"figure.kg-card.kg-bookmark-card:first"`.

The code you want would look more like:

```
$(function () {
  const $container = $('<div></div>');
  
  $container.html(`{{{content}}}`);

  const $figure = $container.find("figure.kg-card.kg-bookmark-card:first");

  getBookmark($figure);
});
```

This would pass the jQuery-wrapped figure node to `getBookmark`.